# Github Actions: warning about set-output, but not using it

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using a GitHub actions to "build" a python app (running linting, code coverage, and tests). At the end of the action I get the following warning:

```
1 warning
build
The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
```

but my **python-app.yml** does not use set-output:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check out
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint pytest pytest-cov
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi

    - name: Lint with pylint
      run: |
        pylint src
      continue-on-error: false

    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
        
    - name: pytest coverage
      run:
        pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml:tests/coverage.xml
    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
```

and so I am not sure how to amend my **.yml** in order to make it compliant for the future.

Comment: There is no mention of the action this warning it is coming from?

Comment: You're not using it _directly_, but have you checked if you're using it _indirectly_? `actions/setup-python@v3` looks to be a major version behind the current release, for example.

Comment: No, there's no additional clue. Copied the whole warning. @jon very good idea. CI newb here :) How do I understand the current version of say actions/setup-python@v3 ? Still copying automation yml files to learn still with limited understanding. Thanks a lot to both!

Comment: https://github.com/actions/setup-python#basic-usage

Comment: Seems like it's been fixed in `@v4` of `actions/setup-python` and you're using `@v3`. Update that to use `@v4`. See https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/578 and https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/578.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your workflow, there may be indirect dependencies on actions that have yet not been updated for [GITHUB_OUTPUT](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) against the [`set-output` deprecation](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

You need to check all the actions in your workflow one by one for version updates with the `set-output` fix.

In your case, visiting https://github.com/actions/setup-python reveals that there's a new version available. And, searching for the `set-output` string in the repo results in relevant references e.g. issues, commit, etc. For example, this issue (https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/578) verifies that it has been fixed in `@v4`.

So, as of now, using `@v4` should fix it i.e.:

```yaml
- uses: actions/setup-python@v4
```

The actions are being updated gradually. Hopefully, all of them will be updated soon and we won't be seeing that warning anymore.

Comment: Thanks so in the future if I use other's actions I might want to look into them for "trouble", right?

Comment: @RobertAlexander: You're welcome! Yes, at least for now. Most of the actions are being updated gradually. Hopefully, we don't have to do that in near future.

Comment: Note: setup-python@v4 works, but setup-python@4.0.0 still results in the deprecation warnings. I was following the GitHub Actions tutorial in *Publishing Python Packages* by Dane Hillard, and ran into this issue.

Comment: @GeoffreySametz: Thank you for pointing that out! I laid out my answer to handle all such issues in a generic way by identifying them one by one. Hope it'll provide a general idea of how to approach these changes.