# The `set-output` command is deprecated; already upgrade to action/core 1.10, issue warning still showing

Tags: github, github-actions

I do have my own github actions but there is a warning im trying to fix (The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files, already upgrade core to 1.10).

I already upgraded my library to core 1.10 as per suggested on the repositories issue but until now, i still encounter issues. Hope someone can help me with my issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions: warning about set-output, but not using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224429/github-actions-warning-about-set-output-but-not-using-it)

Comment: No, that is about the used action. My problem is, im the author of the action

Comment: Are you using `set-output` directly?

Comment: No, im using core.setOuput, from my own action

Comment: https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1218

Comment: Which version of `core` are you using?

Comment: i already upgraded the core to 1.10 as per github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1218

Comment: Then, it looks like it's not been fixed yet. You might want to ask on that thread and may use this [workaround](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1218#issuecomment-1288890856) meanwhile.

Comment: [PR](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/pull/1178) is merged though. That's strange.

Comment: Another relevant issue (https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1336#issue-1575429103) opened recently.

Comment: Verified. [PR # 1178](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/pull/1178/files) has been merged and [core/1.10](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/core/1.10/packages/core/src/core.ts#L185-L200) has these changes. It first checks for `process.env['GITHUB_OUTPUT']` and then proceeds to use the respective `GITHUB_OUTPUT`. Otherwise, it fallbacks to `set-output`. Maybe, you need to review the implementation of your action along these lines.

Comment: that my issue, i already upgraded my core to 1.10 but error still exists

Comment: That update is one thing. You need to verify if it's going through the flow it's supposed to follow and not fallbacks to `set-output`. I'm referring to the existence of `GITHUB_OUTPUT` in the `process.env`. See these [tests](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/pull/1178/files#diff-d1362a421b95042efbcdef91ff8322e92e6e62fb806a61a85acf7137a2a567e4R44-R46), it's setting up these files before. Maybe, it's a bug that it's not automatically being set up. You can test it by setting `GITHUB_OUTPUT` as an env var.

Comment: Finally Fixed!!! The issue was the geneated index.js from ncc build (my building script is ncc build index.js --license licenses.txt) does not include changes from action/core upgrade. I manage to update this using ncc build index.js only

Comment: That's great! Please self-answer this with all the details to help future readers. Thanks!