# The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

Hey guys I am  using sqlfluff to lint my sql files in my github actions workflow. I am using the following [reference](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff-github-actions/tree/main/menu_of_workflows/drizly) in my workflow:

```
# Set the command in the $() brackets as an output to use in later steps
  echo "::set-output name=lintees::$(
  # Issue where grep regular expressions don't work as expected on the
  # Github Actions shell, check dbt-clickhouse/models/ folder
  echo \
  $(echo ${{ steps.get_file_changes.outputs.files_modified }} |
  tr -s ' ' '\n' |
  grep -E '^dbt-clickhouse/models.*[.]sql$' |
  tr -s '\n' ' ') \
  $(echo ${{ steps.get_file_changes.outputs.files_added }} |
  tr -s ' ' '\n' |
  grep -E '^dbt-clickhouse/models.*[.]sql$' |
  tr -s '\n' ' ')
  )"
```

However I am getting th efollowing error: **The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files**

and it leads me to this [website](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/). I tried formatting the above by following the guidlines there:

```
  echo "lintees=$(
  # Issue where grep regular expressions don't work as expected on the
  # Github Actions shell, check dbt-clickhouse/models/ folder
  echo \
  $(echo ${{ steps.get_file_changes.outputs.files_modified }} |
  tr -s ' ' '\n' |
  grep -E '^dbt-clickhouse/models.*[.]sql$' |
  tr -s '\n' ' ') \
  $(echo ${{ steps.get_file_changes.outputs.files_added }} |
  tr -s ' ' '\n' |
  grep -E '^dbt-clickhouse/models.*[.]sql$' |
  tr -s '\n' ' ')
  )">> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

But I am still getting the same error even though I do not have set-output anwywhere else in my yml file. Has anybody used anything similar before? If so could please enlighten me about what I am doing wrong

Comment: you might be using some actions that are still using the old syntax, please share your workflow file and the warning message

Comment: I am using exactly the same workflow as it is in here https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff-github-actions/blob/main/menu_of_workflows/drizly/lint_sqlfluff.yml

Comment: Seems that it's using old versions of many actions, one of them is file-changes which still have an open issue to update this https://github.com/trilom/file-changes-action/issues/141

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions: warning about set-output, but not using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224429/github-actions-warning-about-set-output-but-not-using-it)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't published your workflow file but I suppose some actions in workflow use `core.setOutput` deprecated method. Thus you receive warnings

Like here: [What is the replacement for core.setOutput?](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1218)