# Github actions set output command deprecating

Tags: github-actions

I am new to GitHub environment , am working on data warehouse project where we have dev and production environment, we release dev to production using gitHub actions, when I run deploy the dev environement am getting the following warning

> "The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
> The following actions uses node12 which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node16: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2. For more info: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-13-github-actions-all-actions-will-run-on-node16-instead-of-node12-by-default/
> "

Since am new to this environment I do not know what to do about this warning? Should I have to change the coding in yml file ? Can anyone help me on this please

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to deploy Azure SQL Database

name: Azure SQL Deploy DEV

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

  
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build-and-release"
  build_and_release:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
      - name: Add msbuild to PATH
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
        
      # create dacpac using MSBUILD
      - name: Build dacpac for Database Project
        run: |
          msbuild.exe 'az-pl-dwh/main-dev/sql-server/sql-db-dwh-pl-dev/sql-db-dwh-pl.sqlproj' /p:Configuration=Release

    # Login to Azure for access to Azure Container Registry
      - name: OIDC Login to Azure Public Cloud with AzPowershell (enableAzPSSession true)
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
            client-id: ${{ ****}}
            tenant-id: ${{ ****}}
            subscription-id: ${{ ****}}
            enable-AzPSSession: true

      - uses: Azure/sql-action@v2.1
        with:
            connection-string: 'Server=tcp:sql-alz-ox-dwh-dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sql-db-alz-ox-dwh-oxbo;Authentication=Active Directory Default; Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;'
            # Use the dacpac file from the build job and deploy it to the DEV database
            path: 'az-pl-dwh/main-dev/sql-server/sql-db-dwh-pl-dev/bin/Release/sql-db-dwh-pl.dacpac'
            action: 'Publish'
            build-arguments: '-c Release'                 
            arguments: '/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true /p:DropPermissionsNotInSource=false /p:DropRoleMembersNotInSource=false /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;DatabaseRoles;Permissions;RoleMembership /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions: warning about set-output, but not using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224429/github-actions-warning-about-set-output-but-not-using-it)

Comment: You are using `microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2`. The `set-output` deprecation has been fixed in https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild/releases/tag/v1.1.3 so you need to use this version i.e. v1.1.3 or the later.

Comment: I don't understand much , should I change the version in actions ' uses: actions/checkout@v3' or  change  the msbuild version?

Comment: That warning is about `setup-build` action so that needs to be updated. Try: `uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1.3`